# How can I create a user only for sftp?

Tags: ssh, linux, sftp, upload

I have added a user to the system via the `adduser` tool. Then, in `/etc/passwd`, I tried changing the `/bin/bash` to `/sbin/nologin` or to `/dev/null`, but neither of these worked.

I would like the user not having the option to get an interactive shell, and just to use `sftp`. Is there a way?

I know it's been asked here before but it seems no-one gave a satisfactory response.

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"?

Comment: I meant that the remote scp / sftp didn't work. I solved it using the scponly shell as suggested by Iain

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command you should use to change the shell is  [**chsh**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh). The nologin shell can be `/sbin/nologin` or `/usr/sbin/nologin` (check which you have by looking in `/etc/shells`) but `/bin/false` would probably be a better choice.

```
chsh -s /bin/false user
```

You should consider setting up something like [**scponly**](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki) which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried with the shells inside /etc/shell with no luck... /bin/false gives a "lost connection" and /sbin/nologin returns a "This account is currently not available.". I will try this scponly

Comment: I solved it using the scponly shell! Cheers

Comment: This answer is the needle in the hay! Make sure `/bin/false` and
`/bin/nologin` are actually available in `/etc/shells`!

Comment: @Afri Fine, but... you'll really want to read https://serverfault.com/questions/328395/nologin-in-etc-shells-is-dangerous-why/328424#328424 . This is pretty strongly contraindicated.

Comment: @Afr don't put `nologin` in `/etc/shells`!  https://serverfault.com/a/328424

Answer (score 13):

You should also be able to do it with OpenSSH 4.9 and up, with which you can additionally chroot the user for increased security.

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User user
ChrootDirectory /home/user
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Then run:

```
chsh -s /bin/false user
chown root:root /home/user
mkdir /home/user/uploads
chown user /home/user/uploads
```

The user will only be able to write in /home/user/uploads.

[https://debian-administration.org/article/590/OpenSSH_SFTP_chroot_with_ChrootDirectory](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022230802/https://debian-administration.org/article/590/OpenSSH_SFTP_chroot_with_ChrootDirectory)

Comment: +1 I've put this on my list to investigate.

Comment: I've used it and it works just fine - you can also give the user a choice to log in to the chroot environment with a shell, but in that case you have to copy a minimum of libraries and some other utilities as expected. Jailkit (http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) comes in handy for that.

Comment: Thanks, ForceCommand was a hint. I don't need chroot, but I do want to login to SFTP with service accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is with mysecureshell

http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

You can chroot a user with this easily and even limit bandwidth if needed.

Comment: I solved it using the scponly shell, but It's interessant to know this mysecureshell

Answer (score 1):

You can add a user with `-s /bin/false` to disable their shell, but what you really should look into setting up is a chrooted sftp acccount.  This will "jail" a user into their own directory and prevent them from being able to access or modify any files or directories outside of the chroot directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but It doesn't seem to work. I get a "lost connection" whenever I try a user using the shell /bin/false.