# Making a user with FTP only access in FreeBSD. How?

Tags: ftp, freebsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a user only for sftp](https://serverfault.com/questions/268977/how-can-i-create-a-user-only-for-sftp)

I can't seem to find any brief explanation on how do i allow or add a user with an FTP only access.. This is what i did in order:

1. I made a group "homeftp"
2. I make a user and added it to "homeftp", made it's homedir to Webserver docuroot and nologin as shell.
3. Added this to /etc/ftpchroot: "username" /usr/local/www/folder/

When i try to login to ftp using those credentials, I'm still getting denied by the server.

Where or what am i missing here? Thanks in advance.