# How to create chroot'ed SFTP access on an Archlinux Server?

Tags: ssh, shell, sftp, chroot, arch-linux

I've followed this instructions on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) and [GeekStuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/) to setup an user which can only access the server via SFTP (SSH) but without Shell (`/bin/false`) in a chrooted environment of his home dir.

Nothing much more special, but it simply does not work, I keep getting `access denied` messages when I try to log in. Here is what I've tried so far:

#### SFTP User and Group

The user, here: `user`, is member of the group `sftp`. Home directory is `/srv/sftp/user`. Shell is disable via `/bin/false`

User entry:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ grep -i user /etc/passwd
user:x:1002:1000::/srv/sftp/user:/bin/false
```

Group entry:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ grep -i sftp /etc/group
sftp:x:1000:user
```

Groups of user:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ groups user
users sftp
```

#### Home Directory Configuration

The home directory and all directories above are owned by `root`:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ ls -lsha /srv
total 20K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 17:00 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 15:08 ../
4,0K dr-xr-xr-x  2 root ftp  4,0K 30. Sep 2015  ftp/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 19:30 http/
4,0K drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 17:00 sftp/
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ ls -lsha /srv/sftp
total 12K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 17:00 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 17:00 ../
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 19:34 user/
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ ls -lsha /srv/sftp/user
total 16K
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 19:34 ./
4,0K drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4,0K  4. Apr 17:00 ../
4,0K drwxrwxr-x 6 user sftp 4,0K  4. Apr 20:28 files/
4,0K drwxrwxr-x 2 user sftp 4,0K  4. Apr 19:33 log/
```

#### SSHD Configuration

The end of the SSHD config:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ tail -n16 /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
# override default of no subsystems
### Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp

### This section must be placed at the very end of sshd_config
#   This means that all users in the ‘sftp’ group will be chroot’d
#   to their home directory, where they only will be able to run
#   internal SFTP processes.
Match Group sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

SSHD status:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mo 2016-04-04 23:48:58 CEST; 1 day 15h ago
 Main PID: 9272 (sshd)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           ├─ 9272 /usr/bin/sshd -D
           ├─17597 sshd: user [priv]  
           └─17598 sshd: user [net]   
[...]
Apr 06 15:05:24 host sshd[17597]: Failed password for user from 93.***.***.136 port 45516 ssh2
```

OpenSSH version:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ pacman -Q openssh
openssh 7.2p2-1
```

#### More system information

Kernel version:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ uname -a
Linux host 4.4.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 10 07:38:19 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### Trying to connect

To make sure the password is really correct, I change it to `1234`:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ passwd user
Enter new UNIX password: 1234
Retype new UNIX password: 1234
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Now test with `sftp`:

```
1 ✗ me@client ~ $ sftp -P12345 user@host
user@host's password: 1234
Permission denied, please try again.
user@host's password: 1234
Permission denied, please try again.
user@host's password: 1234
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

This is in the logs, not really helpful at all:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ journalctl -n5
Apr 06 15:34:38 host passwd[25269]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): password changed for user
Apr 06 15:35:26 host sshd[25853]: Failed password for user from 93.***.***.136 port 45834 ssh2
Apr 06 15:35:30 host sshd[25853]: Failed password for user from 93.***.***.136 port 45834 ssh2
Apr 06 15:35:33 host sshd[25853]: Failed password for user from 93.***.***.136 port 45834 ssh2
Apr 06 15:35:34 host sshd[25853]: Connection closed by 93.***.***.136 port 45834 [preauth]
```

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss? How to create chroot'ed SFTP access on an Archlinux Server wihtout shell access?

Comment: make sure you restart `sshd` after changes in config. Can you login locally with that user? Does it work if you change `/bin/false` to `/bin/sh`?

Comment: `sshd` restarted, if I change shell to `/bin/sh` it works. but i dont want to permit shell access.

Comment: `ForceCommand internal-sftp` prohibits shell access. Also if the shell itself is not in `chroot`, it would not be useful.

Comment: ok, found the solution, `/bin/false` was [missing](http://serverfault.com/a/268981/116529) in `/etc/shells`... just took me 2 weeks to find out.

Comment: didnt know `internal-sftp` prohibits shell access. thanks for the pointer to the shell.

Comment: Using `/sbin/nologin` is maybe more appropriate, since it is in `/etc/shells`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the point I missed has something to do with the shell. I tried to login with `/bin/false` as described in many manuals. But that didn't work.

As @Jakuje pointed out, changing that to `/bin/sh` for testing purposes allowed me to login via `sftp`. Hurray! And the interesting fact I also didn't know: `internal-sftp` already prevents `ssh` login.

---

However, who still want's `/bin/false` or `/bin/nologin` as shell, here is what I figured out, finally. Check out if the shells are available in `/etc/shells`:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ cat /etc/shells 
#
# /etc/shells
#

/bin/sh
/bin/bash

# End of file
```

No wonder it didn't work! `false` and `nologin` are not defined! Adding them manually worked out for me:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ cat /etc/shells 
#
# /etc/shells
#

/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/bin/false
/bin/nologin

# End of file
```

Now, just change the shell, with `chsh`:

```
0 ✓ root@host ~ $ chsh -s /bin/false user
Changing shell for user.
Shell changed.
```

Now, `sftp` works in a change-rooted environment and without shell access.